# Set visible of a label from code behind

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net I have this label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="0" visible='<%# visibleCredits() %>'></asp:Label>
```

In code behind I have:

```
protected bool visibleCredits()
{
    return false;

}
```

But the label is always shown, it should be invisible I think. Please don't ask why I did not set:

> Label3.Visible = visibleCredits();

from the code behind.

Comment: Instead of telling us to not ask why, you should tell us why you didn't.

Comment: I have some purposes of doing that. I can not understand why I can not use: visible='<%# visibleCredits() %>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

It will bind your page to the server control and allow you to use data bindings like this.

Answer (score 0):

As Vache suggeseted, you need to call DataBind() since you're using the data binding syntax `<%# visibleCredits() %>`. Alternatively, you can also use `<%= visibleCredits() %>` and not need to call DataBind().